# filter get_children to return all mime types EXCEPT 'x'

Tags: attachments, videos, audio, get-children

Like it says on the tin - Im trying to create a list of post attachments that includes everything except say audio, which I'll feed into a player instead.

- The filter needs to be generic: 'audio' not 'audio/mpeg'.

(For some reason `if ( $mime !== 'audio/mpeg' )` will filter out valid mp3 files –– weird.)

So the following dosen't work:

```
$children = get_children( array('post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment' ) );

            if ( !empty( $children )){
                foreach ( $children as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {
                    $mime = get_post_mime_type($attachment);
                    $url = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID, false );  
                        if ( $mime !== 'audio/mpeg' ) {                                                             
                                $content_attach .= '<a href="' . $url . '"  download="' . $url . '"> ' . $title . ' | ' . $mime . '</a>';
                        }
                }       
             }  
echo apply_filters('the_content', $content_attach );
```

Further listing every audio mime type like so: `if($mime !== 'audio/mpeg' || $mime !== 'audio/ogg')` etc will still leave out those crazy mp3 files.

What does work is:

`$children = get_children( array('post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'audio' ) );`

which will return all the attached audio types in one go - great my player can handel it.

Now I need to *omit* everything that *isn't* audio and list it.

Does anyone have any ideas?

and thanks again for your help and experience. . .

Comment: `if($mime !== 'audio/mpeg' || $mime !== 'audio/mpeg')` is the same as »`If: it is NOT AudioMpeg OR it is NOT AudioMpeg`« ... doesn't make much sense asking the same twice, eh?

Comment: yup! that's a typo - should read `if($mime !== 'audio/mpeg' || $mime !== 'audio/ogg')` –– I've corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is two questions: how to get all the children that are audio, and how to get all the children that *aren't* audio.

1) The `post_mime_type` parameter of `get_children` can actually take a wildcard, so you could use:

```
$children = get_children(array(
     'post_parent' => $post->ID,
     'post_status' => 'inherit',
     'post_type' => 'attachment',
     'post_mime_type => 'audio/%'
));
```

2) You can't do a mime-type exclusion using `get_children`, so you're better off just filtering the whole list to exclude them that way. I think you've got the right idea, just use something like this to exclude all the different kinds of audio:

```
if ( ! strstr($mime, 'audio/') ) {  // ...etc
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but it may help someone

```
    $mime_types = get_allowed_mime_types();
$remove_mime_types = array(
// Image formats
'jpg|jpeg|jpe'                 => 'image/jpeg',
'gif'                          => 'image/gif',
'png'                          => 'image/png',
'bmp'                          => 'image/bmp',
'tif|tiff'                     => 'image/tiff',
'ico'                          => 'image/x-icon'
);

$mime_types = array_diff($mime_types, $remove_mime_types);
```